# Visual Studio 2013 creates larger exe's - no MFC

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I'm a little late with this question, but better late than never.  I've been using Visual Studio 6.0 since it came out, but recently switched to VS 2013 on a new PC.

I've gotten my projects to build under 2013, but the resulting executables it produces are consistently bigger than VS6.0 produced.  I've seen a similar thread on here about that happening in the transition from VS2008 to VS2010, and the comments and suggestions there all seem to attribute the change to changes in MFC libraries that are statically linked in.  But my projects are straight C code.  No C++, let alone MFC.  And the 'Use of MFC' option on my project is set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries" (presumably set by the import tool that generated the 2013-compatible project).  The only non-stadard library it uses is wsock32.lib.

The extra size isn't a killer, but it's a significant relative to the size of the whole app.  My biggest .exe goes from 980Kb to 1.3Mb - about a 35% increase in size to an app whose small size was a selling point (i.e. install this tiny app and you have access to all of our goodies).  That's without debugging info - the increase on the debug version is even more - but I don't really care about that.

Any ideas how to strip out the new cruft - or even to know what it is?

Comment: Historically speaking, linking in one call to "printf" used to bring in a ton of static lib code.  I'm not saying your issue is printf, but it could be some lib call that is now quite heavy due to some new features (e.g. how much functionality has been added to WinSock since VS6?)  Another possibility is security features added to the compiler code-gen since VS6.

Comment: Even if you're unwilling to add a dependency on a separate install of the C++ runtime DLLs, do a build with `/MD`, since that will give a good indication of how much of the size is attributed to your application vs libraries.

Comment: You are catching up with 16 years of processor development and C++ code optimizer improvements.  Bigger code *can* be faster code, inlining and loop unrolling optimizations are much more aggressive thanks to much bigger CPU caches, auto-vectorization and auto-parallelization inevitably use more complex instructions.  And bytes got 100x cheaper, pointless to fret over a 1.3x size increase.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you generate a [MAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx) file on both systems, and figure out the sections that cause the largest contributions.

Anton's answer reminds me: first check if they are both linked the same way (both static or  both dynamic, otherwise it is apples and oranges)

Answer (score 1):

This is [a good manual](http://andrewl.dreamhosters.com/archive/60094446.txt) how to make your binaries smaller.

Basic ideas are the following:

1. Don't forget about Release mode
2. Declare `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`
3. Dynamically link to the C++ runtime
4. Compile the executable without debugging information
5. Compile with /O1, an 'optimize for size' flag
6. Remove iostream and fstream headers, use low level  instead if possible

Comment: #6 also gives you a huge speed increase as a bonus.